# How to listen for enter key, then get value from input text using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension that allows the user to save a current tab url with a name. [image]

My first version gets the input if you press save

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {
    var name = document.getElementById("input_name").value;
    addLink(name);
};
```

[image]

---

To send the value with the enter key instead of clicking the button, I tried to use `onkeypress`, with a function that checked if the key was the enter key. Chrome doesn't seem to like that. It gave me the error message:

```
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following 
Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: 
chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash 
('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline 
execution.
```

---

My latest attempt uses form, since they allow enter key presses.

```
<form id="form" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="submit">
    <input type="text" id="input_name" name="session_name" placeholder="Leave blank for no name" autocomplete="off">
</form>
```

Then I used `addEventListener("input")` to listen for new input, then `addEventListener("submit")` for the enter key

```
document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("input", function() {
    var name = document.getElementById("input_name").value;
    document.getElementById("form").addEventListener("submit", function () {
        addLink(name);
    });
});
```

I added `console.log` to test the code. It pops up, before disappearing right after. I'm stumped, why doesn't the code work, and is there a different way of doing this with Javascript that i'm not getting?

Also, here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytm6qbrg/1/) for manifest and my code.

Comment: `form` reloads the popup page on `submit` event so you need to intercept it and use preventDefault.

Comment: @wOxxOm So that's what's happening. Fixed it, now it works fine. Thanks!